# Basic error in AndroidManifest.xml for SMS receiving permission

Tags: java, android, sms, android-manifest, android-permissions

I know that this has been asked a dozen times before, but I still get the permission error with this xml config. I have scoured the other responses on this. I am using API level 23. Can someone please point out the mistake ? The error is the obvious:

> 09-12 09:13:40.016    1295-1309/? W/BroadcastQueue﹕ Permission Denial:
>   receiving Intent { act=android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED
>   flg=0x8000010 (has extras) } to
>   com.example.richard.simplesmstoast/.SmsReceiver requires
>   android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS due to sender com.android.phone (uid
>   1001)

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".SmsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

Comment: Try placing your <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/> before the <application> tag

Comment: @Vaibhav .. tried that... I've put it all sorts of places :-/

Comment: try making the following changes to your receiver, and if you are reading the SMS you might want to add  

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

 as well

      <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"> 
                <intent-filter android:priority="1000"> 
                    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/> 
                </intent-filter> 
            </receiver>

Comment: @Vaibhav ... Nope :-(

Comment: @RichardGreen did you try my answer?

Comment: "Hey, Where Did My Permission Go?": https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/08/31/hey-where-did-my-permission-go.html

Answer (score 17):

Problem lays in [new permissions model](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html) for Android M (api 23):

> Quickview
>
> - If your app targets the M Preview SDK, it prompts users to grant    permissions at runtime, instead of install time.
> - Users can revoke permissions at any time from the app Settings    screen.
> - Your app needs to check that it has the permissions it needs every    time it runs.

for SMS case documentation bring an example:

> For example, suppose an app lists in its manifest that it needs the
>   SEND_SMS and RECEIVE_SMS permissions, which both belong to
>   android.permission-group.SMS. When the app needs to send a message, it
>   requests the SEND_SMS permission. The system shows the user a dialog
>   box asking if the app can have access to SMS. If the user agrees, the
>   system grants the app the SEND_SMS permission it requested. Later, the
>   app requests RECEIVE_SMS. The system automatically grants this
>   permission, since the user had already approved a permission in the
>   same permission group.

Solutions:

- right way - request permission at first.
- lazy way - set targetSdk 22

Comment: I'm don't normally comment +1's on answers, but because of the open bounty I gotta say this is the right answer. I'm not sure how Android is going to manage compatibility with older apps running on M when it's released, but long term fixes will require adding permission checks throughout your code.

Answer (score 2):

**@Richard Green** :
**Your Logcat throws**

> Permission Denial: receiving Intent {
>   act=android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED flg=0x8000010 (has extras)
>   } to com.example.richard.simplesmstoast/.SmsReceiver requires
>   android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS due to sender com.android.phone

A permission is a restriction limiting access to a part of the code or to data on the device. The limitation is imposed to protect critical data and code that could be misused to distort or damage the user experience.

*I assume that its permissions Problem .*

Please add below
 [Manifest -Permissions](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) 
Above ***Application*** Tag .

```
   <uses-permission android:name="INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

I hope it will helps you .

Answer (score 0):

Your permission should be placed outside and before your application tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Comment: Pretty sure I tried that a few days ago; will re-attempt tonight when I am working on the PC with the SDK installed.

Answer (score 0):

- If you are targeting Marshmallow then you have to request for runtime permission apart from manifest.

Manifest -

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Java Activity class -

```
 final int REQ_CODE = 100;
void requestPermission(){
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        CTLogs.printLogs( "Permission is not granted, requesting");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,Manifest.permission.READ_SMS,Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS}, REQ_CODE);

    } else {
        CTLogs.printLogs("Permission has been granted");
        readSMS();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQ_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            CTLogs.printLogs("Permission has been granted");
            readSMS();
        } else {
            CTLogs.printLogs("Permission denied !!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this worked for me...
Check this out Maybe it will Help You

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="packageName" >
        <intent-filter >

            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />`enter code here`
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>

Answer (score -1):

```
//Requesting permission
private void requestWritePermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        return;

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_SMS)) {
        //If the user has denied the permission previously your code will come to this block
        //Here you can explain why you need this permission
        //Explain here why you need this permission
    }
    //And finally ask for the permission
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_SMS}, WRITE_SMS_PERMISSION_CODE);
}
```

Error on WRTIE_SMS permission

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer? Now it's not clear to understand.